# How to have a cell display the table's name in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

So, basically I want to have a cell show the table's name it is in. I figured out how to get the table ID, starting with 1, but no idea how to get the name of it.

Comment: With the help of the accepted answer I figured it out. For my locale it happened to be "=RECHTS(ZELLE("filename");LÄNGE(ZELLE("filename"))-FINDEN("$";ZELLE("filename")))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't get the name directly. But you could use the [**`CELL function`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#CELL) with its `filename` parameter to get a string containing path, filename and table name of the current cell. Using that string, you can extract the table name as follows:

```bash
=RIGHT(CELL("filename");LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("$";CELL("filename")))
```

Split on multiple lines:

```bash
 =RIGHT(                    # return substring from the right
     CELL("filename");      # of the filename (incl. table name)
     LEN(                   # calculate the length of the table name substring:
          CELL("filename")  # take the complete filename string;
      ) -                   # and subtract ...
      FIND(                 # the position...
          "$";              # of the dollar sign (preceding the table name)
          CELL("filename")  # of the "filename" string
      )
  )
```

<sup>inspired by a [OOo forum post from villeroy](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2319#p10007)</sup>

Depending on your localization, you may have to replace the semicolons `;` by commas `,`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there may be more problems with my localization, it happens to be German.
"=RECHTS(ZELLE("filename"),LÄNGE(ZELLE("filename"))-FINDEN("$",ZELLE("filename")))" Gives me Err:501
If I use semicolon, I get VALUE

Answer (score 0):

I also wondered how to do this. By now it can be done using a short regular expression:

```
=REGAUS(ZELLE("filename");"(?<=\$).+")
```

This look-behind returns the current sheet's name (German localization).